# Inline form input with label over input centered

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a form with long labels over each input and I want the input centered underneath each label but I also need the inputs to stay inline. It should look like this below but the inputs should be centered under each long label.

[image]

Here is what I have but I am having trouble making the inputs center under the labels.

```css
.question-container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#questions {
  margin: 5px 30px;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="form-inline">
    <span id="questions">
        <label>How much will your house cost?</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="input">
      </span>
    <span id="questions">
        <label>What is the most you can pay monthly?</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="input">
      </span>
    <span id="questions">
        <label>What is your Current Monthly Rent?</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="input">
      </span>
  </div>
  <div id='centered'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Bootstrap 4 doesn't have `col-xs` classes, it's renamed to `col`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

Simply had to add `text-align:center;` to the span

```
#questions {
   margin:5px 30px;
   display:inline-block;
   text-align:center;
}
```